# Iterate through DS.hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application I have `Course` and `TeamMember` models, so that each team member can be responsible for several courses:

```
FrontApp.TeamMember = DS.Model.extend({
  name:    DS.attr('string'),
  email:   DS.attr('string'),
  image:   DS.attr('string'),
  courses: DS.hasMany('course', {async: true})
});

FrontApp.Course = DS.Model.extend({
  title:       DS.attr('string'),
  ...
  bunch of other model-specific fields (no relations)
  ...
  ects:        DS.attr('number')
});
```

Now I want to display the following on profile page:

- `is responsible for COURSE_TITLE_1, COURSE_TITLE_2` if he is responsible for <= 2 courses
- `is responsible for COURSE_TITLE_1, COURSE_TITLE_2, ...` if he is responsible for > 2 courses

Currently I am trying to do that from itemController:

```
FrontApp.TeamMemberController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  responsibleForCourses: function(){
    var res = "";

    this.get('courses').then(function(loaded_courses){
        if ( loaded_courses.get('length') <= 2 ) {
            loaded_courses.forEach(function(course){
                res += course.get('title') + " | ";
            })
        } else {
            // access first two of loaded_courses here and add "..."
        } 
        console.log(res); // this thing works
    })

    return res; // but here it does not work
  }.property('courses')
});
```

Since the `model.courses` is a promise, I had to use `.then()`, but this caused the following problem: how do I return my `res` and display it in my template?

Btw, my template looks like this:

```
responsible for courses: {{responsibleForCourses}}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: P.S. I am starting to think that I am trying to do it in a wrong way: maybe I should use views or something else for this purpose...

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript, so once you return the empty string `""` you can't change it later. To solve the issue you can set the property when the promise is resolve.

```
FrontApp.TeamMemberController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  responsibleForCourses: function(){
    var that = this;  
    this.get('courses').then(function(loaded_courses){
      var final_result = "";
      if ( loaded_courses.get('length') <= 2 ) {
        loaded_courses.forEach(function(course){
            final_result += course.get('title') + " | ";
        });          
      } else {
        // access first two of loaded_courses here and add "..."
      } 
      that.set('responsibleForCourses', final_result);
    });
    return ""; // return "" as a temporary value until the promise is resolved
  }.property('courses')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return `res` inside your `then` callback:

```
FrontApp.TeamMemberController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  responsibleForCourses: function(){
    var res = "";
    return this.get('courses').then(function(loaded_courses){
      if ( loaded_courses.get('length') <= 2 ) {
        loaded_courses.forEach(function(course){
            res += course.get('title') + " | ";
        })
      } else {
        // access first two of loaded_courses here and add "..."
      }
      return res;
    })
  }.property('courses')
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: tried, but it does not work =(
If I do return insnde .then() it does not return anything

Comment: @VoloD sorry just added to my answer `return` to the promise itself... does it work then?

Comment: nope =( it returns promise (from console):

Promise {_promiseCallbacks: Object, constructor: function, isRejected: undefined, isFulfilled: undefined, rejectedReason: undefined…}

Comment: @VoloD, did you see the double `return`? first return the promise, and inside the callback the resolved value...

Comment: yes, I tried this http://d.pr/i/DEkH and it returns this http://d.pr/i/MOnw (from console.log(...) ).

sorry for screenshots, not sure how to paste and format code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answers, I solved the problem in a different way:

```
FrontApp.MyTeamController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  firstCourses: Ember.computed(function(){
    return this.get('courses').slice(0,2);
  ).property('courses.@each.title'),

  otherCourses: Ember.computed(function(){
    return this.get('courses').slice(2);
  }).property('courses.@each.title')
})
```

As far as I understand, the problem was in `.property('courses')` instead of `.property('courses.@each.title')`